# Problem with XYZ-Coordinate Systems

Tags: tikz-pgf

Perhaps I made a mistake with the syntax but I think I found a problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x = {(sin(-60) cm,-cos(-60) cm)},
                    y = {(0.866 cm,-0.5 cm)},
                    z = {(0cm,1cm)},
                    scale = 4]  
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1); 
 \draw circle (1);   
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

I can  use `cos(60)` for the second coordinate but I can't use `sin(60)` for the first one.

The question is how to work around this problem. What is the better way ?. 
I can use something like `\xcoord` with `\pgfmathsetmacro\xcoord{sin(-60)}` but perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: use extra curly braces: `{sin(20)}`

Comment: `x = {({sin(-60)},{-cos(-60)})}` works but I can't manage to put cm next to them. I think `\pgfmathparse` is the robust way of doing it. I can also see that a nice answer is coming :)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yes I try the extra curly braces but I can't manage to put cm like percusse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Marco Daniel points out, you can make TikZ parse the expressions by enclosing them in curly braces. To interpret the result as centimetres, you can multiply your expression by `* 1cm`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x = {({sin(-60)*1cm},{-cos(60)*1cm})},
                    y = {(0.866 cm,-0.5 cm)},
                    z = {(0cm,1cm)},
                    scale = 4]  
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1); 
 \draw circle (1);   
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to explain this behavior ? Why the problem appears only on the first coordinate? I see this problem in another answer but I can't find it.